# Django DRF retrieve list of selection (combo box)

Tags: django-rest-framework

Currently, I am developing a web app using Django as backend and vue as frontend. I facing on how to retrieve a list of JSON for selection (combobox)

For example, I create 2 tables (teacher and student, the student have a foreign key of teacher). I already create the API for these 2 tables as below

`api/teacher` (GET, list)

`api/teacher` (POST, create)

`api/teacher/<int>` (GET, view)

`api/teacher/<int>` (PUT, update)

`api/student` (GET, list)

`api/student` (POST, create)

`api/student/<int>` (GET, view)

`api/student/<int>` (PUT, update)

API List is with pagination of 10

The creation of frontend for teacher module is working fine, but when I want to create a student, I need to select the teacher from the list. How do I retrieve the teacher list in a proper way?

At first, I think of using `api/teacher` (GET, list), but this api JSON is restructured with pagination, what if I have more than 10 teachers? I can't show all of them in the combobox

The second way I think is creating one more view for teacher list without using pagination, but I feel the code is redundant and trying to figure the best URL path design.

Anyone can give your opinion or how you do it in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you can give me the code, i can help you in this case, anyway, you can read DRF documentation about viewset... i think `viewset` will resolve your issue:

here you go for documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

and for the pagination documentation, here you go: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/